# What is the correct way to instantiate StandardQueryParser in Lucene 7.1.0?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lucene

I'm trying to create a `StandardQueryParser` in order to `Query` and `Index`, I've already created. I do so in the following line of code:

`StandardQueryParser queryParserHelper = new StandardQueryParser();`

Which causes the following exception to occur at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/search/LegacyNumericRangeQuery
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.builders.StandardQueryTreeBuilder.<init>(StandardQueryTreeBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.StandardQueryParser.<init>(StandardQueryParser.java:110)
    at analysis.Main.main(Main.java:67)
```

*Note* the line 67 is the line of code included above.

I'm using Maven and IntelliJ.

I specify Lucene as a dependency through the following, in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [lucene-queryparser jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-queryparser/7.1.0), as well, to get StandardQueryParser.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I already had lucene-queryparser in my dependency list (in addition to the core listed in the question), when you try to create StandardQueryParser in the way I described above, do you get any errors?

Comment: @Armin - No, your code is fine. Check the version of the QueryParser dependency. All of your lucene dependencies should be the same version (7.1.0).